# onClick react error Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, hover, styles

**I'm getting react Error while trying to change parent component styles onMouseEnter event. How could I change the styles via child component button?
The error is - Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
That seems odd for onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)} is an arrow function.

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-moon-djocul?
**

```js
 // App js
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Categories from "./Categories";
import ShopPage from "./components/Products";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(Categories);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(data);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <ShopPage products={data} filterResult={filterResult} />
    </div>
  );
}


    // Shopping page
    const ShopPage = ({ products }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <Products products={products} />
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };



    // Parent component, the main part goes here
        const Products = ({products}) => {
          const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
          const [style, setStyle] = useState(false);
          if (hovered) {
            setStyle({
              // inline styles
            });
          } else {
            setStyle({
              // inline styles
            });
          }
          return (
            <>
              <Product setHovered={setHovered} style={style} products={products}/>
            </>
          );
        };
        export default Products;

        // Child component
        const Product = ({ setHovered, style, products }) => {
          return (
            <div className={styles.items}>
              {products.map((value) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <div style={style}>
                      <button
                        onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
                        onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
                      >
                        Add to Cart
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        };

        export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are setting setHovered state in component, the simple solution could be to use it in useEffect and add required dependency.

If we talk about your code so you can easily do this by using the state in child component instead of passing through props.

I have updated your code below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-cookies-e6pwxn?file=/src/components/Product.js:141-151

Comment: The idea was by hovering the add to Cart burron chnging styles to the propriete parent div. That's why I'm using the useState in the parent component and passing to the Child Component.

Comment: Now check the sandbox if your need is fullfilled